# Why floor test conducted even after the Oath?

Tags: india

This news trending all over facebook & twitter,

I have a doubt, K. Palanisamy of Tamil Nadu already done oath for Chief Minister position for Tamil Nadu along with ministers on [Thursday](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/chennai/edappadi-palaniswami-ministry-takes-oath-in-tamil-nadu/articleshow/57187126.cms) i.e 16th Feb .

But Governor still conducted floor test for chief Minister Position on [Saturday](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/tamil-nadu-crisis-live-updates-sasikalas-loyalist-e-palanisamy-invited-by-governor-c-vidyasagar-rao-4527637/) 18th Feb, Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "floor test"? My brain reaches out to some sort of assembly vote, but I can't be sure if I'm right.

Comment: @gayhindu Apparently it's a thing? https://www.quora.com/What-is-floor-test / http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_floor_test_in_parliament_of_india

Comment: @gayhindu - You should post that as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is a floor test?

Many people are unfamiliar with the floor test. I was too, but the [Times of India](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/chennai/tn-political-crisis-what-do-floor-test-and-composite-floor-test-mean/articleshow/57150670.cms) lays out the process easily enough.  In parliamentary systems, a government is formed from the parties represented in the legislature.

When one party has a majority this is easy - the chief minister is just chosen by the majority party.

However, when multiple parties are creating a coalition in order to form a government the issue is much trickier. The governor may ask for a vote of confidence in the coalition to prove they have the support necessary to form a government. This is called a *floor test*.

### Why would a floor test occur after the oath has been administered?

A floor test is not required to become minister or form a government. The [Indian Express](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/tamil-nadu-floor-test-edapaddi-palaniswami-wins-vk-sasikala-o-panneerselvam-jayalalithaa-chief-minister-breaking-news-latest-update-4531173/) reported that Palaniswami provided the governor with evidence that his party had decided that he should be Chief Minister. Since his party has a majority, it doesn't matter what the other parties think and he could be safely administered the oath of office.

A better question may be "why was there a floor test at all?". Although I don't have any specific knowledge of the Tamil Nadu legislature, generally confidence votes like this are a good tool for parties to formally show their disapproval as well as a way to root out dissenters in your party. The floor test is more likely a useful political tool, not an important part of the procedure in this case.